# "Add choice" button for respondents in Qualtrics

Tags: button, addition, qualtrics

in my survey, people are asked to list tools they use and I chose form field as question type. Anyway, I would like my respondents to add as many text entrys as they need, currently the number of text entry is predetermined by me. I think of something like a "add choice" button.

So far, I've found this and it works: https://community.qualtrics.com/XMcommunity/discussion/4150/enable-respondent-to-add-extra-response-fields

```
var that=this.questionId;
    jQuery("#"+this.questionId+" tr.ChoiceRow:not(:lt(1))").hide();
    jQuery("<input type='button' id='add' value='Add field' name='+' />").insertAfter("#"+this.questionId+" tr.ChoiceRow:last");
    jQuery("#add").on('click',function(){
        var c= jQuery("tr.ChoiceRow:visible").length;
        jQuery("#"+that+" tr.ChoiceRow:eq("+c+")").show(); 
    });
```

but you have to change the question type "to matrix table", which I would like to avoid. I don't know what and how to adjust the code in order to make it work for form field type of question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code actually adds the button in the wrong place and it could be streamlined.

This will work for a form:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    var cs = jQuery("#"+this.questionId+" .ChoiceStructure");
    cs.find("tr:not(:lt(1))").hide();
    cs.append("<input type='button' id='add' value='Add field' name='+' />");
    jQuery("#add").on('click',function(){
        var c = cs.find("tr:visible").length;
        cs.find("tr:eq("+c+")").show(); 
    });
});
```